# Unble to get save_post to work in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code to update the post_meta when a post is created. It is very simple,just storing the its own post_id in a meta field(might add more in the future)

The following code is not working, I guess it is because the $post_ID is blank, how do I pass the post_id of newly created post to the function update_postmeta (in function.php)?

```
//code from function.php
add_action('save_post', 'update_postmeta');
function update_postmeta($post_ID) {
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'related_id',$post_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good boilerplate for you:

```
function update_postmeta($post_id) {
  global $post;

  // Post meta isn't sent for autosaves
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
  }

  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_id', $rand_id);
}
```

No where in your code is `$rand_id` defined though.

Comment: sorry, fixed now, $rand_id is the $post_id. I see that you are getting the post_id from $post->ID, does this mean I don't need to pass in $post_id to the function?

Comment: Correct, but it *is* passed in